# If and condition

Tags: excel-2010

I am trying to to use this formula for a certain purpose but I am getting a #value! error. Can you please let me know what is wrong with this formula?

```
=IF(AND($B$1<=6,$B$2<=5),"good",""),IF(AND($B$1>=6,$B$2>=5),"average","")
```

Thanks,
Karthik

Comment: Try using ; instead of , as the separator

Answer (score 0):

You're stringing two `IF` formula together rather than combining them.

You have: `=IF(AND($B$1<=6,$B$2<=5),"good","")` and `=IF(AND($B$1>=6,$B$2>=5),"average","")` - a cell can't return two values.

You need embed the second formula where the `FALSE` part of the first formula is:
`=IF(AND($B$1<=6,$B$2<=5),"good",IF(AND($B$1>=6,$B$2>=5),"average",""))`

If the first part returns `FALSE` then the second `IF` formula is calculated - if that returns `FALSE` a blank cell is returned.

Edit - an example of a blank cell would be B1 = 3 (good) and B2 = 10 (average).